# How to dispatch an redux action to load data inside useEffect on page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to integrate redux to an existing react application. I am learning redux. I am using hooks. In the internet there are many examples of using class components. I could not find an example how to achieve this with a function component.

The code below does not throw an error. But, the action inside `useEffect` is not called. The code does not produce any output. I wonder if the call is correct or not. Any help?

**Index.js**

```
const store = createStore(rubricReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));     
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
        <Provider store={store} > <App /> </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>,
    rootElement);
```

**Rubrics.tsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    rubrics: state.rubrics.items,
    loading: state.rubrics.loading,
    error: state.rubrics.error
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getRubrics: () => dispatch(fetchRubrics())
    };
}

const Rubrics = (props) => {    
    const { rubrics, loading, error } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        props.dispatch(fetchRubrics());
    }, []);    

    if (error) { return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>; }    
    if (loading) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }    

    return (    
        <ul>
            <React.Fragment>
                {rubrics.map(rubric => {
                        return (
                            <li key={rubric.id}>{rubric.title}</li>

                        );
                    })}
            </React.Fragment>
        </ul>
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Rubrics);
```

**rubricActions.tsx:**

```
export function fetchRubrics() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchRubricsBegin());

        axios.get("api/Rubric/Index")
            .then(response => {
                console.log('success: reading rubrics');

                dispatch(fetchRubricsSuccess(response.data));
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => { fetchRubricsFailure(error) });
    };
}

export const FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN = "FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN";
export const FETCH_RUBRICS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_RUBRICS_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_RUBRICS_FAILURE = "FETCH_RUBRICS_FAILURE";

const fetchRubricsBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN
})

const fetchRubricsSuccess= (rubrics) => ({
    type: FETCH_RUBRICS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { rubrics}
})


const fetchRubricsFailure = (error) => ({
    type: FETCH_RUBRICS_FAILURE,
    payload: {error}
})
```

**rubricReducer.tsx** :

```
import {
    FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN,
    FETCH_RUBRICS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_RUBRICS_FAILURE
} from '../_actions/rubricActions';

const initialState = {
    rubrics: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

const rubricReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            };

        case FETCH_RUBRICS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                items: action.payload.rubrics
            }
        case FETCH_RUBRICS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.error,
                items: []
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default rubricReducer;
```

Comment: `useEffect` looks good to me. You might want to check whether `fetchRubrics` is working fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) provided by [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) since v7.1.0, this can be now written without `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


const Rubrics = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { rubrics, loading, error } = useSelector(
    state => ({
      error: state.error,
      rubrics: state.rubrics,
      loading: state.loading
    })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRubrics());
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (error) { return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>; }
  if (loading) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }

  return (
    <ul>
      <React.Fragment>
        {rubrics.map(rubric => {
          return (
            <li key={rubric.id}>{rubric.title}</li>
          );
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    </ul>
  )
};
```

Comment: It is wise that useEffect includes dispatch as dependency

Comment: You know, I had an error where I coded ```const dispatch = useDispatch;``` and I had this error 'Invalid hook call'. Just coded ```const dispatch = useDispatch(); with parenthesis and it worked fine. it's crazy man.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you are using incorrectly mapDispatchToProps. You don't need to set explicitly the dispatch function, that is what react redux does for you.

So, below is the correct way to do it:

```js
// Now you won't be creating a new object every time your component re-renders
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getRubrics: fetchRubrics
}

const Rubrics = (props) => {    
  const { getRubrics } = props;

  // You should always add elements inside your render scope
  // to the second array parameter of useEffect to prevent unexpected bugs.
  useEffect(() => {
      getRubrics();
  }, [getRubrics]);

  return (    
    <div>Your component here!</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your dispatch mapping you have

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getRubrics: () => dispatch(fetchRubrics())
    };
}
```

so instead of calling `props.dispatch(fetchRubrics());` just call `props.getRubrics()` or destructurize this method from props

```js
const { rubrics, loading, error, getRubrics } = props;
```

and just call `getRubrics()`

Comment: Does `FETCH_RUBRICS_BEGIN` action get dispatched? Also this may be a silly question, but I assume you use redux-thunk or any similar middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct code:

```
const Rubrics = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllRubrics();
    }, [])


    return (
        props.rubrics.map((rubric) => {
            return (<RubricCard rubric={rubric} />)
        })
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    error: state.error,
    rubrics: state.rubrics,
    loading: state.oading
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { fetchAllRubrics: () => dispatch(fetchRubricsData()) }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Rubrics);
```