# Redux action (fetch from db) not firing when useEffect() is called

Tags: redux, react-redux, use-effect

I am trying to build an eCommerce website to learn Redux.

At the moment I am trying to fetch the categories when the component mounts. Since I am using functional components, I understood that this is achieved by calling the useEffect() method.

Also, I am using json-server as a REST Api.

I am quite sure I have managed to compose my enhancers to pass to the store (dev tools and thunk), created actions, reducers and all.

My problem is that the action doesn't fire when the component mounts.

N.B. before introducing the Middleware and therefore the fetch request, everything worked just fine. Also consider that the fetch request is successful.

Hereafter is the code involved.

'src/index.js'

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, /* preloadedState, */
  composedEnhancers
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

the action type in 'actions/index.js':

```
export const FETCH_CATEGORIES = 'FETCH_CATEGORIES'
```

the action creator in 'actions/index.js':

```
export const fetchCategories = () => (dispatch) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:7000/categories")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(categories => {
            return {
                type: FETCH_CATEGORIES,
                payload: categories
            }
        })

}
```

'reducers/index.js'

```
import * as actions from './../actions'

const initState = {
    categories: [],
    currentCategory: 'any',
    toggler: 'hidden'
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SELECT_CATEGORY:
            return { ...state, currentCategory: action.payload.value }
        case actions.FETCH_CATEGORIES:
            return { ...state, categories: action.payload }
        case actions.TOGGLE:
            return { ...state, toggler: action.payload.toggler }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default rootReducer
```

the 'Filter.js' component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { selectCategory, fetchCategories } from '../../../../actions'



const Filter = (props) => {

    // const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState(0)
    // const handleMinPrice = event => {
    //     setMinPrice(event.target.value)
    // }

    // const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(0)
    // const handleMaxPrice = event => {
    //     setMaxPrice(event.target.value)
    // }

    // const [department, setDepartment] = useState("select")
    // const handleDepartment = event => {
    //     console.log(event.target.value)
    //     setDepartment(event.target.value)
    // }
    // console.log(props);


    const handleChange = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.selectCategory(event.target.value)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchCategories()
    })


    return (
        <div className="filter-form col-12">
            <form id="filter-category">
                <label htmlFor="category">Category</label>
                <select className="col-12" id="category" name="category" size="5" value={props.currentCategory} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>
                    {props.categories.map(category => <option key={category.value} value={category.value}>{category.name}</option>)}
                </select>
            </form>
            {props.currentCategory !== 'any' && <form id="filter-department">
                <label htmlFor="department">Department</label>
                <select className="col-12" id="department" name="department" size="5" value='{department}' onChange='{handleDepartment}'>
                    <option value="select">--- Select ---</option>
                    <option value="desktop PCs">Desktop PCs</option>
                    <option value="laptops">Laptops</option>
                    <option value="gamepads">Gamepads</option>
                    <option value="headphones">Headphones</option>
                    <option value="microphones">Microphones</option>
                    <option value="keyboards">Keyboards</option>
                </select>
            </form>}
            {/* <form id="filter-price">
                <label htmlFor="minimum-price">Min. Price: {minPrice}£</label>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value={minPrice} className="slider col-xs-12" id="minimum-price" onChange={handleMinPrice} />
                <label htmlFor="maximum-price">Max. Price: {maxPrice}£</label>
                <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" value={maxPrice} className="slider col-xs-12" id="maximum-price" onChange={handleMaxPrice} />
            </form> */}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        categories: state.categories,
        currentCategory: state.currentCategory
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        selectCategory: (value) => {
            dispatch(selectCategory(value))
        },
        fetchCategories: () => {
            dispatch(fetchCategories())
        }

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filter);
```

Also, here is 'db.json'

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": "any",
      "name": "--- Any ---",
      "departments": []
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "value": "computers-and-accessories",
      "name": "Computers and Accessories",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "desktop-pc",
          "name": "Desktop PCs"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": "laptops",
          "name": "Laptops"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": "keyboards",
          "name": "Keyboards"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "value": "headphones",
          "name": "Headphones"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "value": "mouses",
          "name": "Mouses"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "value": "gamepads",
          "name": "Gamepads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "value": "fashion",
      "name": "Fashion",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "dresses",
          "name": "dresses"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": "shoes",
          "name": "Shoes"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": "pants",
          "name": "Pants"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "value": "sunglasses",
          "name": "Sunglasses"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "value": "handbags",
          "name": "Handbags"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "value": "hats",
          "name": "Hats"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "value": "digital-music",
      "name": "Digital Music",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "rock",
          "name": "Rock"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": "pop",
          "name": "Pop"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": "house-and-techno",
          "name": "House and Techno"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "value": "trap",
          "name": "Trap"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "value": "indie",
          "name": "Indie"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "value": "hip-hop",
          "name": "Hip-Hop"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "value": "house",
      "name": "House",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "kitchen",
          "name": "kitchen"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": "garden",
          "name": "Garden"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": "bedroom",
          "name": "Bedroom"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "value": "bathroom",
          "name": "Bathroom"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "value": "livingroom",
          "name": "Livingroom"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "value": "cleaning",
          "name": "Cleaning"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "value": "grocery",
      "name": "Grocery",
      "departments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "vegetables",
          "name": "Vegetables"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "value": "pasta and rice",
          "name": "Pasta and Rice"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "value": "snacks",
          "name": "Snacks"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "value": "canned-food",
          "name": "Canned Food"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "value": "frozen",
          "name": "Frozen"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "value": "dairy",
          "name": "Dairy"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work when you call ```fetchCategories()``` outside of useEffect?

Comment: As a side note include empty brackets as second arg of useEffect if you only want it to run on mount  ```useEffect(() => {props.fetchCategories()}, [])```

Comment: @Grant Singleton, I have tried to call it outside the useEffect right before it and doesn't work. must be the way I map dispatch to props, or the way I implement the action. I have also tried this solution :'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633900/how-to-dispatch-an-redux-action-to-load-data-inside-useeffect-on-page-load/55634105', but still not working

Comment: Also, I am aware of the second arg with empty brackets :)

Comment: console.log() inside the action to see if it is firing. Then console.log() inside the reducer. Find out if the action or the reducer isnt firing. I havent seen the syntax you are using to dispatch to the reducer inside the action so that may be the issue but im not sure yet.

Comment: It isn't logging from the action, nor the reducer. Must definitely be that (dispatch) parameter I am passing inside the action creator. The problem is that if I don't pass it I get `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dispatching like this in the action which will fire the reducer FETCH_CATEGORIES:

```
export const fetchCategories = () => (dispatch) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:7000/categories")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(categories => {
            // **Changes start here
            dispatch ({
                type: FETCH_CATEGORIES,
                payload: categories
            })
            // **Changes end here
        })

}
```

Comment: OMG thanks! Is it this the proper way to handle a fetch request with use effect? If there is a best practice could you post a link? Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it since useEffect is replacing componentDidMount here. My only suggestion would be to add the ```[]``` so the fetch only runs on mount. Without it you may end up fetching more than you need. If you want to prove this to yourself try logging to the console inside useEffect to see when it is running.

Comment: Here is a good article on it https://blog.bitsrc.io/fetching-data-in-react-using-hooks-c6fdd71cb24a

Comment: One more https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data